# Windows 8, Ubuntu problem, Bios

Tags: 13.04, bios

I bought a samsung 370R, it has BIOS version P07RAN, I followed the instruction to install 13.04, it created partition all good and then

whenever I restart computer, and hit on "ubuntu" as one of the options to load, it gives me this error
"Windows failed to start....

```
File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr

Status: 0xc000007b

Info: The application or operating system could not be loaded because required file is missing or contains error
```

Big thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: wubi does NOT work with 13.04.

Comment: Try to uninstall from within Windows and follow the instructions in [Installing on a pre-installed Windows 8 system UEFI supported](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: in case you want to delete Windows 8 : you should delete the recovery partition then too, when you want to install Ubuntu ( after disabled uefi in bios and enabled efi in bios ).